# Send mail from command line with mailx-8-1-1

Tags: linux, email, redhat, postfix-mta, mailx

I would like to send an email from command line, the problem is that I need,
like option of the command mail or mailx, -r (sender).
My command doesn't have this option, because is an old distribution.
I have:

> Linux version 2.6.18-128.el5 (mockbuild@hs20-bc1-5.build.redhat.com) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-44))

This is mailx version:

> Package mailx-8.1.1-44.2.2.i386

I configured in postfix the configuration of main.cf correctly, because
I tried the same script with another machine updated at the version 6, 
and run very well because there is the option -r

This is my script

```
mail -s "Test mail" -r $SENDER $RECEIVER
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: What happens when you run the command? What error do you get?

Comment: When i run the script I receive this: 

mail: invalid option -- r
Usage: mail [-iInv] [-s subject] [-c cc-addr] [-b bcc-addr] to-addr ...
            [-- sendmail-options ...]
       mail [-iInNv] -f [name]
       mail [-iInNv] [-u user]